# quick Edit module not working in drupal 7.5

Tags: php, backbone.js, drupal-7

I tried inline-editing using quick edit module.I ahve included ctool,library,entities and two js files.(ie) backbone.js and underscore.js in (site/all/libraries) and granted permission for 'Access in-place editing' and 'Use contextual links' as administrator.
After enabled the modules I can see the inline edit icon but I cant edit.
Does I want to do any other steps to enable editing.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same problem in drupal 7, i resolve it by

1. Downloading backbone and underscore js from  [url](https://github.com/Tajtaj/backbone-and-underscore/archive/master.zip)
2. Extract them into libraries folder of drupal 7 separately
3. Clear the cache [Drupal cache]

[image]